# onSaveInstanceState not working as expected

Tags: android

I have a button that goes from one activity to another activity and its supposed to save the value int Counter, but every time it never saves. What am I doing wrong? I have seen other solutions, but i check and im doing the exact same thing as them.

```
package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button myButton;
private int Counter;
private Button myButton2;
private TextView myTextView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        add = savedInstanceState.getInt("Count");
        Counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("Add");
    }

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Counter = ButtonCounter(Counter);
        }
    });
    myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Counter = AutoCounter(Counter, add);
            Display(Counter, myTextView);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }, 10);


}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Count", Counter);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Add", add);
}


public int ButtonCounter(int Counter) {
    Counter += 1;
    return Counter;
}

public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
    Counter += add;
    return Counter;
}

public void Display(int Counter, TextView myTextView) {
    String man = String.valueOf(Counter);
    myTextView.setText("$" + man);
}



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not implementing the right method

from the docs:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Count", Counter);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Add", add);

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#oncreate

Comment: i have changed it, but it still doesnt work
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Count", Counter);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Add", add);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

Comment: this lines:
`if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        add = savedInstanceState.getInt("Count");
        Counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("Add");
  }`


should be:
`if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        add = savedInstanceState.getInt("Add");
        Counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("Counter");
  }`

Comment: what you get when you output the counter?

Comment: Also notice you never initialized the variable add so when you call `AutoCounter(Counter, add);` your counter does not increment

Comment: When i output the activity on the second activity it works, but when i go back to the main activity it goes back to 0

Comment: yeah the add value is 0 just until i have this data erasing set

Comment: how would i do that??

Comment: do you modify the counter on activity 2 or you just show it and come back?

Comment: as onResume is called when you come back to activity1 Try overriding onResume(activity1) and there retrieve the savedinstancestate values.

Comment: i modify it and then use Intent.putextra() to return it

Comment: on onResume 
`Intent intent = getIntent();
then intent.getStringExtra("string"); or in your case your counter
`